# SQLAlchemy + Scrapy: Primary Key already exists error incorrectly

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, scrapy

I am trying to pipeline my Scrapy scraped data straight into a postgresql database using SQLAlchemy. I have managed to get a connection, however, nothing is being written and I get the error on every item being written to the database:

```
DETAIL: Key (hash_id)=(2122600700) already exists.
[SQL: 'UPDATE spider SET hash_id=%(hash_id)s'] [parameters: {'hash_id': 2122600700}]
```

This is not true, as I have checked my database (only have 60 items) and I tried scraping items with different primary keys (hash_ids). I must be missing something in how SQLAlchemy and Scrapy handles the items, these are my pipeline:

pipeline.py

```
class PgPipeline(object):
    def __init__(self):
        """
        Initializes database connection.
        Reflects the spider table.
        """
        engine = db_connect()
        self.spiderDB = load_table(engine)
        self.conn = engine.connect()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        """Save listings in the database.

        This method is called for every item pipeline component.
        """
        stmt = self.spiderDB.update().values(item)
        self.conn.execute(stmt)
        return item

    def close_spider(self, spider):
        self.conn.close()
```

models.py

```
metadata = MetaData()


def db_connect():
    """
    Performs database connection using database settings from settings.py.
    Returns sqlalchemy engine instance
    """
    return create_engine(URL(**settings.DATABASE))


def load_table(engine):
    """
    Reflects the spider table in the DB
    """
    return Table('spider', metadata, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)
```

Really hope one of you can help me as I have been scratching my head awhile on this one!

Comment: Were you suppose to use `insert` instead of `update`? `update` is used to modify entries which have been stored in the table.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This actually starts writing things to the database. I was looking for the postgresq 'upsert' and incorrectly read that update command would work for this... I will have to add additional commands for that functionality I guess

Comment: The "upsert" is documented in the dialect specific part here: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/postgresql.html#insert-on-conflict-upsert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used update incorrectly, so using insert() instead worked like a charm. Also adding on the suggested on_conflict from the docs solved my problem. Worked!